# Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources' image_picker with Flutter

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I am getting this issue `Execution failed for task`:app:processReleaseResources`using`image_picker`widget with Flutter, I saw that`image_picker`is built with`minSdkVersion`as`16`, and when that's changed, it fails, I am using`21`as`minSdkVersion`, and`compileSdkVersion`&`targetSdkVersion`as`27`, I have tried to change the`targetSdkVersion`to`16`but I got some issues cuz I have some plugin dependencies with`21`.

This is the issue:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:137: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeReleaseResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:137: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\42d72a25de05c0a46e75cddecb240d5d\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\release\processReleaseResources\out\resources-release.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processReleaseResources\resources-list-for-resources-release.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\release\processReleaseResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.archangelsystems.tagueo\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\intermediates\symbols\release\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0.aar\4889927745807dec05ed4fe733f46abb\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.0.aar\4889927745807dec05ed4fe733f46abb\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\42d72a25de05c0a46e75cddecb240d5d\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\release\processReleaseResources\out\resources-release.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processReleaseResources\resources-list-for-resources-release.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\release\processReleaseResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.archangelsystems.tagueo\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\joseph.arriaza\Desktop\proyects\tagueoflutter\build\app\intermediates\symbols\release\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       8.7s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I was not able

Comment: I switched to image_picker_modern @Joseph Arriaza

Answer (score 0):

These resources (fontVariationSettings and ttcIndex) were added in API 28, so you need to update your compile SDK version to 28.

Comment: if I update it, I get this: D8: Program type already present: android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserCompat$CallbackHandler
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForRelease'.
And also this The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.